# The correct way of handling SqlAlchemy session in celery

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, celery

I found it is quite hard to understand the correct way of handling session in Celery, probably because I don't understand it much.

Let's say I have a **celery.py** define as below:

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    scoped_session,
    sessionmaker,
    )

DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker())

from celery.signals import worker_init
@worker_init.connect
def bootstrap(signal, sender):
    engine = create_engine('postgresql://hello:world@localhost/db')
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)

celery = Celery(include=[
            'tasks',
            ])
celery.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
celery.settings=None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    celery.start()
```

I am not sure if scoped_session should be used, I have seen some samples around using it but I think Celery got nothing to do with scope?

**Question 1: What kind of session should I use?**

**Question 2: Should I use the siginal worker_init? Or Just use a module level session?**

After the session has been created, how do we actually release/remove/close it?

**tasks.py**

```
from .celery import celery, DBSession

@celery.task
def do_task():
    DBSession.query(some_object).all()
    #some logics
    DBSession.commit()
    DBSession.remove()
```

Does scoped_session affect which function to use?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you end up finding the answer to this on your own?